# Why does mean squared error decrease when the number of trees is increased in Random Forest?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, binary-decision-diagram

I am using random forest to model a response variable. When I look at the OOB plot the Mean squared error plummets with increase in the number of trees. What is the explanation to that decrease?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, more trees is equivalent to more features/parameters in your model. A higher number of features in an ML model always reduces training error. This is simply due to the fact that if those additional features are unhelpful, then those features will not be used and the training error will at least remain the same as the model with fewer features.

This however does not mean that adding more features/parameters is always a good idea as a reduction in training error does not imply reduction in generalization error. In other words, your model could be overfitting on the training data but may not show error reduction on test data. A good approach to finding the ideal number of trees is to plot the test error with increase in number of trees and select that number at which the test error starts plateau-ing.

Comment: how can I get the test error? Matlab gives me only the OOB for the training data

Comment: You should separate your data randomly into a training and a testing set. For starters, 80% training and 20% test should be a decent split. Once you train the model on your training set, you can evaluate on the test set and obtain the test error. If you are new to ML, I recommend reading the first few chapters of Andrew Ng's book - Machine Learning Yearning https://www.deeplearning.ai/machine-learning-yearning/.

Comment: @MichaelGetachew please do not use the comments space to ask new follow-up questions, irrelevant to your original one; if you have a new issue you are always welcome to open a new question